# Get Duplicate Records with Primary Key

Tags: sql

iam using sqso I have 3 fields:

```
ID        CustomerNo        Date
1           0009                9/9/2011
2           0009                9/9/2011
3           0009                9/9/2011
4           0010                9/9/2011
```

i want to determine the records with the same customerno and date and get each of their unique id.

```
ID        CustomerNo        Date
1           0009                9/9/2011
2           0009                9/9/2011
3           0009                9/9/2011
```

How can I do this? i tried this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S1.ID,  S1.customerno, S1.DATE
FROM TABLE AS S1
INNER JOIN TABLE AS S2
ON  S1.DATE=S2.DATE AND S1.CUSTOMERNO=S2.CUSTOMERNO 
AND S2.id <= S1.id
GROUP BY S1.customerno, S1.id , S1.DATE
```

but it also get the record no.4, different customer no but with the same date.

i want to get only those that are duplicate in customerno and date.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand you correctly, the duplicate customer numbers and dates are given by this query. (My table is just named "t"; I can't use "table" as a table name.)

```
select customerno, date
from t
group by customerno, date
having count(*) >= 2
```

To get the ID numbers for those "duplicated" customers, join that to the original table.

```
select t.id, t.customerno, t.date
from t
inner join
    (select customerno, date
     from t
     group by customerno, date
     having count(*) >= 2) dups 
  on dups.customerno = t.customerno and dups.date = t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT S1.ID,  S1.customerno, S1.DATE 
FROM TABLE AS S1 
INNER JOIN TABLE AS S2 ON S1.DATE = S2.DATE 
WHERE 
    S1.DATE = S2.DATE 
    AND S1.CUSTOMERNO = S2.CUSTOMERNO 
    AND S2.id <= S1.id 
GROUP BY 
    S1.customerno, S1.id , S1.DATE
```

Try this code

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

If "CustomerNo" is the unique id you are talking about then this query may work for you.

```
Select Count(*) as #OfDuplicates, CustomerNo, Date
From Table
Group By CustomerNo, Date
Having Count(*)>1
```

Or this query can be used if you would like the last row's key as a sample reference. This also avoids using a subquery.

```
Select Count(*) as #OfDuplicates, CustomerNo, Date, Max(Id) as SampleInstanceId
From Table
Group By CustomerNo, Date
Having Count(*)>1
```